# YouTube Data Api and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api

I've been able to set up a toy app with the following code taken from YouTube's sample ruby [projects](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/ruby/search.rb). I'm looking to use YouTube to search for artists channels, playlists, videos. No issues with the sample toy app but can't get the same code working in Rails.

After successfully searching YouTube's API and manipulating the response, I've tried importing some of this code into an existing rails app.

I initially put the following code into a new initializer in my `config` directory but when trying to load rails console to play with the query, I'm receiving the following error:

"NameError: uninitialized constant Google"

```
require 'google/api_client

client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :key => "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  :authorization => nil,
  :application_name => $PROGRAM_NAME,
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
)
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'
```

I know there's been some updates to the API but having trouble tracking down exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `require 'google/api_client'` to the file where you're instantiating that client variable?

Comment: Yes, still getting an error. "cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)"

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error using Ruby 2.6.5 in a Rails 6 app. I found [this similar issue on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/132#issuecomment-56062366) and downgrading the `google-api-client` gem solved it for me.

I used

```rb
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.7.1'
```